# Почему typeof 1 / 0 возвращает NaN , а не number

Tags: javascript

Недавно начал учить JS и столкнулся с непоняткой. Если в переменную положить Infinity `let a = 1 / 0` и проверить `typeof` то результат будет number. Если же не класть в переменную 1 / 0, а проверить сразу, то результат будет `NaN`. Почему так происходит?

```
let a = 1 / 0

console.log(a) // Infinity
console.log(typeof 1/ 0) // NaN
console.log(typeof a); // number
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Команда `typeof` принимает только один аргумент. И при делении строки на ноль возвращается `NaN`;

```
( typeof 1 ) / 0 => 'number' / 0 => NaN
```

Правильнее использовать скобки :

```
typeof ( 1 / 0 ) => 'number'
```